# Method call while closing a bootstrap modal popup

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to redirect to a page while closing a modal popup. But that's not happening.

I am trying to redirect to a page either by using

`state.go()` or by `location.path()`.

Here is the confirmation pop - up code in angular :

```
function modalMessage($rootScope,result) {
    $rootScope.FinalMessage = result.finalMessage;
    $rootScope.ReasonOrTransKey = result.ReasonOrTransKey;
    $rootScope.ConfirmationMessage = result.ConfirmationMessage;

    //Finds element with attribute iConfirmationModal
    angular.element("#iConfirmationModal").modal();
}
```

When the user clicks on the close() button I want put my redirect code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

since the jqLite does not support `modal` method, you should use `$` instead of `angular.element`

[Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/61xTC8x5Us5tlrKdS4rY?p=preview)

```
function modalMessage($rootScope,result) {
     $rootScope.FinalMessage = result.finalMessage;
     $rootScope.ReasonOrTransKey = result.ReasonOrTransKey;
     $rootScope.ConfirmationMessage = result.ConfirmationMessage;

     //Finds element with attribute iConfirmationModal
     $("#iConfirmationModal").modal();
     $("#iConfirmationModal").on('hidden', function(){
        $timeout(function(){
            $state.go(...)
        })
     })
}
```

Comment: $timeout(function(){
            $state.go(...)
        }) What's this for ? Can you please explain .. ?

Comment: Did not work :( ... what else to do ? It does not redirect .

Comment: please see my updates, i think the reason is you are using `angular.element` which does not support `modal`

Answer (score 0):

This event is fired when the modal has finished being hidden from the user (will wait for css transitions to complete).

```
angular.element("#iConfirmationModal").on('hidden', function () {
  // do something…
})
```

http://getbootstrap.com/2.3.2/javascript.html#modals

Comment: But when I do `angular.element("#iConfirmationModal").on('hidden', function () {
  $location.path('\transaction\search');
})` ... does not work :(

Comment: try this..
$(element).on('hidden.bs.modal', function(){
          scope.$apply(function(){
          //do something
          });
        });